# ImportError: cannot import name QWebEngineView

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWebEngineView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
view = QWebEngineView()
view.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
window.setCentralWidget(view)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is exactly the error I get in code like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eymen\Desktop\qtweb.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWebEngineView
ImportError: cannot import name 'QWebEngineView' from 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' (C:\Users\eymen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtWidgets.pyd)
```

But my pyqt5 version is the most up-to-date and I don't see any errors. I thought it was related to the Python version but I couldn't get an idea. Python version: 3.11.1 alternative libraries do not satisfy my request.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWebEngineView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
view = QWebEngineView()
view.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
window.setCentralWidget(view)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried this code but when it should show google.com in python window it gave error and said QWebEngineView library not supported

Comment: No, it never said that "QWebEngineView library not supported" (which isn't a standard error message): it clearly said that QWebEngineView is *not* part of the QtWidget module, which is completely different. Whenever in doubt, always check the documentation, as a *good* one always shows to which submodule a class belongs; for Qt, always look at the top of the official C++ API (you can normally discard PyQt/PySide docs): the `qmake` section normally hints about the Python module, which, for QWebEngineView is `webenginewidgets` (aka: `from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
```

Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
view = QWebEngineView()
view.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
window.setCentralWidget(view)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```